# Ruby Syntax, using numbers in symbols?

Tags: ruby, syntax, symbols

I'm new to ruby and Chef and am running to an issue with syntax when defining attributes in my cookbook. Below is relevant code:

```
default[:my_cookbook][:stuff] = {
:foo_bar => {
:grok => ['Hi'],
:2grok => ['Bye'],
...
```

It appears I can't use a number to begin 2grok.. Is there a way to escape this, or what would be the proper syntax to use '2grok'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to start a symbol with a digit, you need to enclose it in quotes:

```
:'2grok' => ['Hi']
```

If you use double quotes, ruby [interpolates](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbols) string inside:

```
:"#{1 + 1}grok"
```

Also, you can use [percent-notation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings):

```
%s{2grok}
```

Finally, you can get the symbol by calling [`to_sym`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_sym) method on a String:

```
'2grok'.to_sym => ['Hi']
```

Answer (score 2):

Mladen's answer is correct in term of Ruby. You can use a number at the beginning of symbol's name only using quotes. Keep in mind that you will have to use them to access the value from hash too. However you **shouldn't** use symbols for defining attributes in your cookbooks. [Chef Style Guide recommends using strings instead](https://docs.chef.io/ruby.html#symbols-or-strings).